# Default source and stock missing in MSI after re-enabled - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, stock, msi, multi-source-inventory

We disabled all the below MSI extensions.

```
Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
```

We again enabled all the above MSI extensions for salable qty feature. After that we have checked in **Admin -> Stores ->  Inventory -> Sources/Stocks**, both sources and stocks are empty. Before disable we have default source and default stock.

please provide suggestions to restore the default source and stock?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you got any solution?